# How would you convert an image to JSON in Lua?

Tags: json, lua, roblox

As you all have probably guessed, I've been trying to make an image parser in a heavily modified and sandboxed version of Lua known as "RBX.Lua" on the kids' gaming platform "ROBLOX".

It is limited and sandboxed heavily to protect from harming the site or engine.
Anyway, is there any way in normal Lua to convert an online image (.png, .jpg, etc) to JSON?

This will probably be closed due to being submissive, and I acknowledge that - I just want to see if there is any way to convert an image into JSON so it returns a JSON table of all the pixel data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you'll have a hard time reconstructing it inside Roblox if you intend to display it. There's no way to give raw image data to GUIs, you'd have to do some trickery and create a frame for every pixel of the image, which isn't very practical.

Otherwise try converting the image data to base64 and then back again. As it'd still be highly compressed you'd have to do the jpg or png decoding in lua. Painful.

Comment: Most people take the approach of converting to base64 and then converting that to JSON - ROBLOX has a function called "JSONDecode" which decodes JSON tables and returns them as Lua tables, so then they would use that to just get data of every pixel - then, they'd set the GUIs properties (Color, etc) to the data in the JSON table.